# Version of python script

Tags: python, windows, file, properties, version

I was wondering if it is possible to set a version to a python script. I would like to be able to see the version of a script by right clicking on the file, selecting properties and then select the version tab.

This tab exists on many other files, but is it possible to lure it out on a .py/.pyw file?

Comment: Typically you'd version a script with the `__version__` attribute, but the OS won't pick that up.

Comment: Yea I found that as well, I guess that only works if I want to find out the version inside the script (or from another program).

Comment: That's usually what matters! I don't think I've ever needed to look at the "version" from the OS side. If you want to do that, you could write something that extracts that attribute from the file content and updates the file properties accordingly (perhaps on a pre-commit hook, to keep it up-to-date as you commit your changes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are textfiles and thus they don't contain any header to include such information.

Specify the version with `__version__` attribute and ask Microsoft to write this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

`__version__` is a string, but sometimes it's also a float or tuple. You should also make sure that the version number conforms to the format described in [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) ([PEP 386](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/) a previous version of this standard).

```
__version__ = '1.0'
```

or

```
__version__ = (1, 0)
__version__ = sys.version[:3]
```